# How to load charts in background using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've been using few type of google's charts (l load the Google Charts with Ajax) in my apps. 
Before I can do anything in my application I have to wait until all the charts have been loaded. So it takes time. I would like to load charts in the background so that I can continue using the application. 
I've already tried setTimeout, promise function but it didn't work. 
I am asking for any advice.
Thank you :)

This is one of my charts:

```
DesktopManager.loadMonthChart = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: Routing.generate('...'),
        success: function (data) {
            DesktopManager.showContentAndHideLoader('window-month-chart');
            var dataForChart = [];
            for (var value in data.values) {
                dataForChart.push([value, data.values[value]]);
            }
            google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataForChart);
                var options = {
                    title: '',
                    animation: {
                        startup: true,
                        duration: 5000,
                        easing: 'out',
                    },
                    curveType: 'function',
                    legend: {position: 'none'},
                    hAxis: {textPosition: 'none'},
                    backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
                    colors: ['#7cab30']
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('desktop-item-chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
            DesktopManager.showErrorMessage('window-month-chart');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Without code it is very hard to give feedback. Provide a small example code how you use the charts.